# Trying to understand the reasons for establishing the 'criteria of substitution'.

Tags: logic

In *Theory of Sets* by *N. Bourbaki*, the author discusses some criteria named *Criteria of Substitution* while writing the reason for establishing that in the following excerpt:

> Formal mathematics contains only explicitly written assemblies. Nevertheless,
>   even with the use of abbreviating symbols, the development of
>   mathematics strictly in accordance with this principle would lead to
>   extremely long chains of reasoning. For this reason we shall establish
>   *criteria* relating to indeterminate assemblies; each of these criteria will
>   describe once for all the final result of a definite sequence of manipulations
>   on these assemblies. These criteria are therefore not indispensable to
>   the theory; their justification belongs to *metamathematics.*

I'm having some problems in comprehending the statements in the above excerpt.

$\bullet$ Why does "even with the use of abbreviating symbols, the development of mathematics strictly in accordance with this principle would lead to
extremely long chains of reasoning"?

Could anyone please help me visualise what the author meant to say?

Also,

$\bullet$ Why did the author write the criteria are not "*indispensable* to the theory"?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question, you need to be aware that the authors of Bourbaki had some very odd ideas about logic. In particular they adopted a definition of the logical quantifiers in terms of Hilbert's choice function. This is extraordinarily inefficient when compared with the standard approach in mathematical logic. See [Adrian Mathias's delightful paper on this](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/inefff.pdf). Essentially, when Bourbaki wrote "even with the use of abbreviating symbols ... would lead to extremely long chains of reasoning", in fact, Bourbaki's bad choice of "abbreviating" symbols was the cause of the problem.

I can't comment on the second part of your question just now as I don't have the relevant volume of Bourbaki in front of me.

Comment: +1 for Mathias' paper (although I think his first name is "Adrian").

Comment: @Noah: you are quite right. Thank you. I've corrected my answer.